# Handling duplicate inserts of records by timestamp in DB2

Tags: database, insert, timestamp, db2, db2-luw

Using DB2 9.7.5, I have two tables, the master table and the importing table. Every hour I get a data dump which is inserted into the importing table. I then merge the records from the importing table into the master table. To differenciate an existing record in the master table all records are timestamped to the second.

Both tables are defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    STATUS VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    ACTION_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) IN SOME_TABLE_SPACE;
```

Before merging the importing table into the master table I delete existing records in the importing table.

```
DELETE FROM IMPORTING
WHERE (ACTION_DATE) IN
    (SELECT ACTION_DATE FROM MASTER);
```

The only records within the importing table should be new ones, therefore I insert the records from the importing table to the master table.

```
INSERT INTO MASTER (STATUS, ACTION_DATE)
SELECT STATUS, ACTION_DATE FROM IMPORTING;
```

The problem which I encounter from time to time is I get duplicate records because the ACTION_DATE is sometimes off by a up to 2 seconds between the master and importing tables

So how do I delete records form the importing table which have a timestamp offset of 2 seconds in the master table?

Comment: Unrelated to that, have you looked at the MERGE statement?

Comment: @data_henrik a MERGE works on equality does it not?

Comment: How do you determine that they are duplicates? Is there a surrogate key or a natural key that you should be using for merging?

Comment: Whatever YOU are using to determine they are duplicates should be what your Delete statement uses to remove them from the import table.

Comment: @Wes H and Mao, The ACTION_DATE is kind of acting like a key, but sometimes the same record is duplicated because the ACTION_DATE is off by a few seconds. I was thinking of using the SECONDS function and determine if the difference is within 2 then they would be the same. I just don't know how to implement it in the delete.

Comment: @GeekyDaddy there will never be a date range that is safe enough.  You are looking at something else to determine there is a duplicate.  Otherwise you wouldn't know that a difference of 2 seconds is duplicate and not a new record.  You need to use a real key.

Comment: "The problem which I encounter from time to time is I get duplicate records because the ACTION_DATE is sometimes off by a up to 2 seconds between the master and importing tables" - um, **HOW**?  If it was `time1` in the import table, it should be `time1` in the master table, period.  For that matter, why aren't you clearing the entire table?  Or even using a separate import table, if they both look like that?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, I'm trying to compensate for a system which I didn't design. The data coming into the Importing table is out of my control, but I'm responsible for ensuring accuracy. The data coming into the importing table arrives from many sources and time zones. Some groups will insert their data from one source and another group will insert from another. Again out of my control.

Comment: ...okay, but that doesn't change the fact that your current workflow would completely clear the prior set of rows.  And I agree with Wes here - you need a real key.  For one thing, what happens if the rows form a sequence with a 1-second separation between elements, where the ends may be hours apart?  How do you tell which is the "real" one?  Or where they should have been divided, if there are multiple?  A timestamp is rarely a unique key, it's almost always attribute data about an item.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates issue, you can change insert sql to insert only those records that do not exist in master table.

INSERT INTO MASTER (STATUS, ACTION_DATE)
SELECT STATUS, ACTION_DATE FROM IMPORTING I
WHERE not exists
    (SELECT 1 FROM MASTER M
     where m.ACTION_DATE = i.ACTION_DATE);

Comment: A record in the master table with a timestamp of '2018-01-25 13:14:43' is equal to a record in the importing table with a timestamp of '2018-01-25 13:14:42'. If I were to insert, then the record would be inserted, but if I can determine that the record falls within a 2 sec time difference then it considered the same and would not be inserted.

Comment: INSERT INTO MASTER (STATUS, ACTION_DATE) SELECT STATUS, ACTION_DATE FROM IMPORTING I WHERE not exists
    (SELECT 1 FROM MASTER M
      where m.ACTION_DATE between i.ACTION_DATE and i.action_date + 2 seconds);